# Push VS Code Project to GitHub with folders

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I'm pretty new to GitHub, i searched all over the internet for pushing an entire project from Visual Studio Code to GitHub but I haven't found anything that would allow me to send, with the codes, the folders. Example : index.html is in **Html\Version1\bin**

How can I upload all this folders including what's inside assuming that there really is something inside? Thanks

Comment: Are you aware that you have a dedicated git tool in the side bar, the "Source Control" pane? If so, where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: that was simply what I was searching for. I'm so sorry but I could not find any tipe of tutorial to solve my problem. Ty @ÁlvaroGonzález

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created your local repository with `git init` ?
And assigned the remote repository location?

```
#example set a new remote

git remote add my_awesome_new_remote_repo git@git.assembla.com:portfolio/space.space_name.git
```